# Delete HBase values from a single column for all rows in HBase shell

Tags: hbase

I have a HBase table t01, having 3 column families (say F1, F2, F3).
Each Column Family has many columns.
I need to delete all values from a single column (say F1:C01 where C01 is the column qualifier).
Is there anything I can combine with a delete (filter or ...) to delete all those values in a single command?
Something like:

I'm working with HBase 1.1.2. 
We don't have Hive or any other additional layer on top of HBase.

```
delete 't01', {ROWPREFIXFILTER => '*'}, 'F1:C01'
```

Comment: The easiest way I found is to implement an extra command via a ruby script. See those references for further details: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499848/hbase-shell-call-hbase-command-on-scan-results
https://layer4.fr/blog/2016/12/23/hbase-fun-in-the-shell/